# Is there a standard format for names of values in documentation

Tags: formatting

I was writing a small cheatsheet for some of the vim commands I use frequently, just for personal reference. I ran into a problem when I realized that [square brackets] were used in the regex formatting, but I had been using them to show values. For example, I had the substitute command written as

```
%s/[existing string]/[replacement string]/g
```

Is there a standard format in documentation for values like these?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For vim you would write:
`%s/<EXISTING STRING>/<REPLACEMENT STRING>/g`

Square brackets are commonly used in conjunction with the perl Template module:

[% EXISTING_STRING %]

Documentation:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Template